# Unit Testing a Service with Moq & xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

Sorry, this is likely a very amateur question, but I am struggling to understand how to use Moq properly. I am quite new to unit testing as a whole, but I think I'm *starting* to get the hang of it.

So here's my question... I have this snippet of code below which is using a `TestServer` in Visual Studio that I using for am Unit Testing... I'm trying to mock `IGamesByPublisher` so that my test is not reliant on data in the repository (or would it be better to mock `GamesByPublisher`?... Or do I need to do both?)

```
public static TestServerWithRepositoryService => new TestServer(services =>
{
    services.AddScoped<IGamesByPublisher, GamesByPublisher(); 
}).AddAuthorization("fake.account", null);


[Fact] // 200 - Response, Happy Path
public async Task GamesByPublisher_GamesByPublisherLookup_ValidRequestData_Produces200()
{

    // Arrange
    var server = ServerWithRepositoryService;

    // Act
    var response = await server.GetAsync(Uri);

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(response);
    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);

}
```

Here is the `IGamesByPublisher`

```
public interface IGamesByPublisher interface.
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Publisher>> Execute(GamesByPublisherQueryOptions options);
    }
}
```

I tried

```
public static TestServerWithRepositoryService => new TestServer(services =>
{
    services.AddScoped<Mock<IGamesByPublisher>, Mock<GamesByPublisher>>(); 
}).AddAuthorization("fake.account", null);
```

And then I tried

```
// Not exactly what I attempted, but that code is long gone... 
var mock = new Mock<IGamesByPublisher >();
var foo = new GamesByPublisherQueryOptions();
mock.Setup(x => x.Execute(foo)).Returns(true);
```

I didn't really find great documentation on using Moq, just the quick start guide on GitHub, which I wasn't sure how to apply (probably my own level of experience at fault there...).

I am obviously missing some fundamentals on using Moq...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close.

```
public static TestServerWithRepositoryService => new TestServer(services => {
    var mock = new Mock<IGamesByPublisher>();

    var publishers = new List<Publisher>() {
        //...populate as needed
    };

    mock
        .Setup(_ => _.Execute(It.IsAny<GamesByPublisherQueryOptions>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(() => publishers);
    services.RemoveAll<IGamesByPublisher>();
    services.AddScoped<IGamesByPublisher>(sp => mock.Object); 
}).AddAuthorization("fake.account", null);
```

The above creates the mock, sets  up its expected behavior to return a list of publishers any time `Execute` is invoked with a `GamesByPublisherQueryOptions`.

It then removes any registrations of the desired interface to avoid conflicts and then registers the service to return the mock any time the interface is requested to be resolved.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting an error on the Return(true); My guess is this should be something else other than a Boolean? Great idea on removing the registrations!

Error: CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Publisher>>' Project.WebApi.Test

Comment: @TravisWoodward. I fixed it. I mis-read the interface and used what you had setup for the mock, not realizing that it did not match the interface definition..

Comment: Thanks so much, this really helped me. Now I can do some more research on why it's being done this way to understand it more.